# Gradle Build failed for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am new to Gradle.I am using Gradle 4.3 version.I am trying to configure a spring -boot application using gradle but it getting failed during project build phase.

Please find below my **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.10.RELEASE"
}
apply plugin: 'java-library'
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile(
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
        'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
     )
    }
   }
```

During gradle building from eclipse I am using `build` command,I am getting following error in eclipse console:

```
Working Directory: D:\Maven_Workspace\AddGradleViewer
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\Sumit\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Local installation at C:\Users\Sumit\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.3
Gradle Version: 4.3
Java Home: C:\Java\Java8\Jre8
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: true
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: build

:compileJava FAILED
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
 > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:.
  Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.jar 
    Required by:
    project :
 > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
       Searched in the following locations:
       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.pom
       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web//spring-boot-starter-web-.jar
       Required by:
       project :
 > Could not find org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:.
       Searched in the following locations:
       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper//tomcat-embed-jasper-.pom
       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper//tomcat-embed-jasper-.jar
       Required by:
       project :
 > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:.
       Searched in the following locations:
       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf//spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-.pom
       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf//spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-.jar
       Required by:
       project :
```

Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this?

Comment: I took your build file, removed the last curly brace which should be there, installed the 4.3 version of gradle using the wrapper, added a dummy Spring boot main class (the same as the one in the reference guide), and it builds fine. I would use the latest version of both Spring Boot (2.0.0), and Gradle (4.6), but except for the curly brace that shouldn't be there, everything is fine.

Comment: OK.Thanks.it worked now.

Comment: @ JB Nizet good comment more than an answer.